# cypress spy on function call from react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I want to spy on a function which is defined in a separate file and called by multiple react components.

For example, I have this test.js file:

```
export const func = {
  call: (e) => console.log(e),
};
```

This is imported by multiple React components and I want to spy on this function with cypress but its never called:

```
import { func } from "../../src/test";

describe("template spec", () => {
  it("calls func.call", () => {    
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.spy(func, "call");
    //some more code ...
    expect(func.call).to.be.called
  });
});
```

The goal of my test is to validate the network traffic from my app to the backend and backwards over rest and socket.io. Because it's necessary that the app can be used without the real backend for presentation and testing purpose, I mocked the fetch function and socket events to simulate the backend, which can be enabled by an environment variable. And it's required that the test can run without the backend running. The problem is on the one hand that i need a possibility to test my socket.io traffic, which is not possible with cypress, like I read and on the other hand that cy.intercept for fetch is not working as expected. I manged to intercept the fetch calls and redirect them to my mock function but it seems that the original fetch body is already kind of serialized and I cannot easily get the original fetch body. This is especially tricky when it comes to formdata body.

I'm new to testing with cypress, so I might have misunderstood the concept of spying. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can answer the question about your spy.

When you import `func` inside the test you are getting a different instance of the function to the one the app is using.

If you want to successfully spy on it, you must pass the same instance from the app to the test.

The accepted way to do that is to put `func` on the `window` object. For example, in `App.js` in the React code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { func } from "../../src/test"

if (window.Cypress) {   // check if Cypress is running
  window.func = func
}

function App() {
  const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';

  return <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

Now in your test, you will successfully spy on `func` like this

```js
it("calls func.call", () => {    

  cy.visit('/', {
    onBeforeLoad: (window) => {          // IMPORTANT spy must be set first!!! 
      cy.spy(window, 'func').as('func')  // spy on func property, setting an alias
  })

  //some more code ...

  cy.get('@func').should('have.been.called')
})
```

Reference: for more examples [Bahmutov - Spies, Stubs & Clocks](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/commands/spies-stubs-clocks.html)

Comment: Thank you! Already tried your approach but must have missed something... But now it works like expected. The only thing i had to add was to wait for the function to be not undefined with cy.window().its("mock") .then((mockObject) => ...})

Answer (score -2):

To test the WebSocket, There is a library for Cypress

https://github.com/lensesio/cypress-websocket-testing

The same is also listed on the Cypress plugin webpage.

https://docs.cypress.io/plugins

Here you'll find many plugins which will help you with many of your future problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your cypress output also shows 0 calls for the spy function. Even when i move the func.call() directly in the App.js like you proposed, the spy is not being called.

Comment: Before I proceed with your answer, I need information on that are you proceeding with E2E testing or component testing?

Comment: I'm using the E2E testing setup

Comment: Here You are doing wrong! The flow/process you wish to test with react is made for component testing. 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/react/overview
Please refer to this doc. 
Also, spy behaviour is different. In E2E testing, It cannot properly spy a react component method due to its virtual behaviour. Since Cypress cannot find a method in dom, It'll not spy, Although you can spy network calls etc with spy which I'm using to interact between API/endpoint requests and more.
Also, Can you let me know your exact test case, There are numerous ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the question with my test case. Is spy working different in component-testing and E2E testing? Is spying on my function possible in component-testing?

Comment: As I see now your updated question, Correct me if I understood it wrong. 
Your actual test is to spy on network requests so you can identify a request is made or not, and you may need to execute your cases accordingly.
Right? 
Please confirm.

Comment: I've edited the current answer. Please review and let me know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: Yes, partly correct. I want to validate that the request body is correct and have to mock the response (rest and socket.io). But I dont want to write the response mocking again for the test because it is already implemented in the app. So i want either to reuse my mocking-function inside my tests or directly spy on my mocking function.